# Git copy branch before rebasing?

Tags: git, rebase

Lets say you have `feature_branch` off `main` and want to rebase it on top of `main` to pick up the latest changes.

I often see people recommending to make a copy of your branch before doing a rebase in case you screw up, so you can revert your changes.

My question is, is this practise still required if you're working with a remote repository?

So all your changes are already pushed to remote, and you perform the rebase on your local checkout. Surely if it goes wrong, you can just reset your local checkout back to the remote?

Or can something go wrong during the push?

Comment: Even without a remote, you already have a snapshot of your branch you can revert to - just make a note of the tip's commit ID (or find it later with `reflog`).

Comment: So can you use that even if you have pushed? For example, if you have done a successful rebase AND pushed, but then decide the rebase was a mistake, assuming you knew what the HEAD commit hash was before the rebase, just do a 'git reset --hard <HEAD commit hash>' then do a 'git push -f' and you return back to where you were before the rebase on both remote AND local? (this all assumes I am the only person working on the branch, so no risk to other peoples work)

Comment: Your example sounds correct, yes.  Unreferenced commits _do_ get garbage-collected after a few days, so tag the commit or make a branch there if you might want to return to that state very much later.

Comment: If you do a rebase that you don't like: go back to the (pseudo?) ref `ORIG_HEAD`. That's where you were before you did it. (PS: “orig” here has nothing to do with “origin”.)